# How secure is the traffic behind the SSH tunnel to VPS virtual server?

Tags: server, ssh, vps

If I buy a VPS virtual server on the net, and establish a `ssh` tunnel to it: how secure is my communication?
Between my machine and the VPS is probably quite secure. But what about the traffic behind the VPS?

I mean especially in terms of passwords, banking details etc: could they be read by the VPS hosting provider? Or anyone else?

Comment: This depends on the connections you make. Connections from the VPS to anything are basically the same as if you would connect from your machine directly. In general, Connection security is mostly defined by the target machine security settings for the connection, not the route or your client.

Comment: You ask "How secure is a SSH tunnel to VPS virtual server?" then "what about the traffic behind the VPS?". Which is it?

Comment: How is this related to Ubuntu? This question would be much better on [Security.SE].

Answer (score 1):

The VPS **will be able** to see

- Websites/Serveraddresses you connect to.
- Unencrypted contents (http, ftp, ...)

The VPS **won't be able** to see

- Encrypted contents (https, sftp, ssh, ...)

> **Note**: This is a general concern. You always have to use *https* **OR** trust your provider (and any node between you and the server) to not steal your passwords etc.

In terms of sneaking on which websites you visit, you always have to trust someone. It's just a matter who you trust more. Be it your VPS provider, your VPN provider, your ISP or your boss at work.

That said, there are networks that *try* to prevent that by rerouting your traffic through several nodes (e.g. [TOR](https://www.torproject.org/)).